The "�" sign instead of Cyrillic characters in a .net project running in docker
I get the � sign instead of any Cyrillic characters output by the project.
The application runs in docker. Here is my Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PatiVerCore.WebApi/PatiVerCore.WebApi.csproj", "PatiVerCore.WebApi/"]
COPY ["PatiVerCore.Application/PatiVerCore.Application.csproj", "PatiVerCore.Application/"]
COPY ["PatiVerCore.Domain/PatiVerCore.Domain.csproj", "PatiVerCore.Domain/"]
COPY ["PatiVerCore.Infrastructure/PatiVerCore.Infrastructure.csproj", "PatiVerCore.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["PatiVerCore.Persistence/PatiVerCore.Persistence.csproj", "PatiVerCore.Persistence/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./PatiVerCore.WebApi/./PatiVerCore.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PatiVerCore.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "./PatiVerCore.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./PatiVerCore.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PatiVerCore.WebApi.dll"]

This is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:

  pativercore.webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}pativercorewebapi
    container_name: pativer-core
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PatiVerCore.WebApi/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5001:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis_cache

  redis_cache:
    image: redis:7.4.0-alpine3.20
    container_name: redis-cache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server

For example, I'm trying to display a word on the page: app.MapGet("/", () => "Приветик!");

I know that the symbols are displayed correctly on the local computer in docker-desktop, but not on the Linux (Debian) server.
I tried to connect to docker and output the message echo  "Приветик!" - the recording was displayed correctly
I tried to add locale to dockerfile, but it didn't help me.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales

# Locale
RUN sed -i -e \
  's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
   && locale-gen

ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU:ru
ENV LC_LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8

# +Timezone
ENV TZ Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

I feel like I'm dealing with something supernatural!
Console.WriteLine($"Кодировка: {Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName}");
Console.WriteLine($"Кодировка: {Console.OutputEncoding.WebName}");

Result:
localetest-1  | ���������: Unicode (UTF-8)
localetest-1  | ���������: utf-8


The problem is probably with the client and how it interprets the output of your application. What client are you using? A browser? Curl? Postman?

I tried to display the message in the browser, in the console, and even wrote it to the database. The same result is everywhere

The editing of the source does not happen not in UTF-8, but say Windows-1251 and then the source is compiled with UTF-8, needing to substitute the corrupt bytes.
By \uXXXX escaping it will work.
Console.WriteLine($"\u041A\u043E\u0434\u0438\u0440\u043E\u0432\u043A\u0430...");

It might be the VS remote editor using the wrong Windows encoding.

You were right. The VS editor automatically changed the encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1252(ANSI) when I wrote Cyrillic to the file.

I would first try adding the below to your code if you haven't already.
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Alternatively if you are on a Windows client connecting to the server try following these steps.
https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Hi, friend. Thanks for the reply, but adding this line did not affect the display of the text in any way

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
